# Github actions on pull request and master branch

Tags: github, github-actions

Github actions is still in beta and pretty new, but I hope someone can help regardless. I thought it would be possible to run github actions on the master branch and on pull requests, like this:

```
on:
  pull_request
  push:
    branches: master
```

But this doesn't work, and throws the error

> yaml: line 4: mapping values are not allowed in this context

. Instead I can only get it to work like this:

```
on: [pull_request, push]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you are just missing a colon after `pull_request`. This works for me.

```
on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches: master
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Test
        run: echo "done"
```

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation**

Each trigger has to be defined as a property that defines an object.

Each object defines overrides for default settings.

There are 3 possible syntax you can use:

**Minimal syntax:**

```
on:
  pull_request:
  push: { branches: [master] }
```

**Explicit syntax:**

```
on:
  pull_request: {}
  push: { branches: [master] }
```

**Extendable syntax:**

```
on:
  pull_request:
  push: 
    branches: 
      - master
```

When using a version control system the latter may be most useful as diff viewers can always easily distinguish* between different lines.

**Although modern diff viewers can also easily distinguish inline differences.*